# How to get the difference between two dates in days from users input in asp.net using Java script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to do some calculation and get the difference of 2 dates that user enters to the textboxes and display it in a label or textbox.
One of my dates is a fixed date and is displayed in a label called Asofdate.
Second date will be entered by user in the DOL textbox.

[Here is the image of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrQFo.jpg)

Here is my html code:

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:left; width:80px">&nbsp;As of Date: </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAsOfDate" runat="server" Text="04/15/2018">/asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="ColWidth">
        <span class="red" style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">*</span>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDOL" runat="server" Text="DOL "></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td class="InputCallWidth" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOL" runat="server" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
             Height="25px" Width="120px" Enabled="True" onkeyup="getTotalDaysDown();" 
             ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />                        
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender3"
                runat="server"
                ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"
                AutoComplete="false"
                MaskType="Date"
                Mask="99/99/9999"
                InputDirection="LeftToRight"
                TargetControlID="txtDOL">
        </ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator3"
                ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender3"
                runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="txtDOL"
                IsValidEmpty="False"
                EmptyValueMessage="Date is Required!"
                Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="logSave" 
                InvalidValueMessage='Invalid Date!' Font-Size="Smaller" 
                Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"
                MaximumValue="12/31/9999" MaximumValueMessage="Invalid Date!" 
                MinimumValue="1/1/1754 " MinimumValueMessage="Invalid Date!">
         </ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator>
    </td>
<tr>
```

And Here is the part where I use my script to do the calculations.
This is the formula: (AsOfDate - Dol) + 1

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getTotalDaysDown() {
       //Here is the part that I have problem. I can't get the values from label and textbox. 
       var AsOfDate = document.getElementById("lblAsOfDate").value;
       var DOL = document.getElementById("txtDOL").value;
       var diff = (new Date(AsOfDate) - new Date(DOL)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

       //I don't get no result populated in my lblDaysDown label.
       //In the console I get the error that "Cannot read property 'value' of null"
       document.getElementById('<%=lblDaysDown.ClientID %>').innerHTML = (diff + 1);
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have to use embedded code blocks if you use `ClientIDMode="Static"` on all controls (or set it permanently it in `web.config`). You can just use `document.getElementById("lblAsOfDate")`. There are a lot of "date diff" questions on SO, make sure you search. I haven't checked the JS; what isn't working?

Comment: @wazz I'm not able to retrieve the value from my text box and label in the script. The calculation part for counting the difference work fine if I pass the fixed dates into the variable in the script itself. But when I try to retrieve the value it doesn't.

Comment: What do you get in `AsOfDate` and `DOL`? `undefined`? an element? error?

Comment: @egvaldes I get nothing populated in my label. My label will stay balnk

Comment: In your JS code, when you define `AsOfDate` and `DOL` you are already getting the value, which means those vars will be strings, then when you do the calculation you get the value property again, which will be undefined, you have to get rid of `.value` either in the declaration or in the calculation.
You should be getting an Invalid Date error when you do `new Date(AsOfDate.value)`

Comment: @egvaldes I got rid of .value in my var diff part and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Asuming everything is ok in the ASP side and you are getting the IDs right, this should work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getTotalDaysDown() {
       //Here is the part that I have problem. I can't get the values from label and textbox. 

       var AsOfDate = new Date(document.getElementById("<%=lblAsOfDate.ClientID %>").innerHTML); //Value should be 04/15/2018 according to your image
       var DOL = new Date(document.getElementById("<%=txtDOL.ClientID %>").value); //Value should be 11/01/2017 according to your image
       var diff = (AsOfDate - DOL) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

       document.getElementById('<%=lblDaysDown.ClientID %>').innerHTML = (diff + 1);
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I still get NaN instead of 155

Comment: @user2116846 What is getting stored in AsOfDate and DOL vars? Those should be Date objects

Comment: they are dates. Look at the picture that I have included. You can find it using the link provided.

Comment: Just in the txtDOL i'm using ajaxtoolkitcontrol date mask. Which I have included in the above code in html section.

Comment: @user2116846 If when you do `document.getElementById("<%=txtDOL.ClientID %>").value`  you get a string whit the date, it doesn´t matter. I suggest you use the debugger and go step by step on the function execution.

Comment: @user2116846 check my updated answer, I just realized you were using value for a label in `var AsOfDate = new Date(document.getElementById("<%=lblAsOfDate.ClientID %>").value)` labels don´t have a value, we have to use `innerHTML`, like you do whit the other label.

Comment: @egvales Ya now it works the problem was with the label. thanks a lot